# remove fields which are added by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, there are three fields which are dynamically added by jQuery. For adding fields, my code is working fine, but when I want to remove those dynamically added fields, my remove fields code is not working.

Here is my code:

```
function clone_row() {
    $('#add_more_fields').before('<div class="new_field"><div  class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin><div class="uk-width-medium-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><label for="site Type">Product <span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text" name="product_require[]" data-parsley-trigger="change" required  class="md-input" /></div></div>
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><labelfor="site_area">Quantity<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text" name="quantity[]"  data-parsley-trigger="change" required  class="md-input" /><input type="hidden" name="numb_array[]" value="0" class="form-control array-class" /></div></div>
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><select id="select_demo_1" name="quantity_type[]" class="md-input"id="val_select" required data-md-selectize><option value="">Select Quantity Type</option><option value="Cubic Yard">Cubic Yard</option><option value="Ton">Ton</option><option value="Piece">Piece</option></select></div></div></div><div class="uk-grid">
<div class="uk-width-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><button type="button" onclick="close_me(this)"; class="md-btn md-btn-primary pull-right">remove</button></br></div></div></div></div></div> ');
}

function close_me(me) {
    $(me).parent('new_field').remove();
}
```

Comment: Avoid inline JavaScript and in your case use event delegation with `.on()` to handle the removal.

Comment: In case you wish to be able to remove field one by one, than you could keep their references in an array... But as I sad that could help in case you wish to control and manage each field separately...

Comment: The added markup is invalid: https://jsfiddle.net/w9060qjv/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the dot to specify the parent class you're searching for. Also there is a typo into your html clone_row() function.

Here is correct the answer : https://jsfiddle.net/5ufsfLz1/7/

```
function clone_row() {
    $('#add_more_fields').before('<div class="new_field"><div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin><div class="uk-width-medium-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><label for="site Type">Product <span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text" name="product_require[]" data-parsley-trigger="change" required class="md-input" /></div></div><div class="uk-width-medium-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><label for="site_area">Quantity<span class="req">*</span></label><input type="text" name="quantity[]" data-parsley-trigger="change" required class="md-input" /><input type="hidden" name="numb_array[]" value="0" class="form-control array-class" /></div></div><div class="uk-width-medium-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><select id="select_demo_1" name="quantity_type[]" class="md-input" id="val_select" required data-md-selectize><option value="">Select Quantity Type</option><option value="Cubic Yard">Cubic Yard</option><option value="Ton">Ton</option><option value="Piece">Piece</option></select></div></div></div><div class="uk-grid"><div class="uk-width-1-1"><div class="parsley-row"><button type="button" onclick="close_me(this)" ; class="md-btn md-btn-primary pull-right">remove</button><br></div>    </div>  </div></div>');
}

function close_me(me) {
    $(me).parents('.new_field').remove();
}
```

With the correct HTML :

```
<div class="new_field">
  <div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
      <div class="parsley-row">
        <label for="site Type">Product <span class="req">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="product_require[]" data-parsley-trigger="change" required class="md-input" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
      <div class="parsley-row">
        <label for="site_area">Quantity<span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="quantity[]" data-parsley-trigger="change" required class="md-input" />
          <input type="hidden" name="numb_array[]" value="0" class="form-control array-class" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1">
      <div class="parsley-row">
        <select id="select_demo_1" name="quantity_type[]" class="md-input" id="val_select" required data-md-selectize>
          <option value="">Select Quantity Type</option>
          <option value="Cubic Yard">Cubic Yard</option>
          <option value="Ton">Ton</option>
          <option value="Piece">Piece</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-1-1">
      <div class="parsley-row">
        <button type="button" onclick="close_me(this)" ; class="md-btn md-btn-primary pull-right">remove</button>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="add_more_fields">

</div>
<a id="more" href="#" onClick="clone_row()">Click me</a>
```

Comment: I edited my answer. Please take a look, i attached a jsfiddle to solve your issue, Ramandeep Kaur.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
 function close_me(me)
 {
   $(document).find('.new_field').remove();  
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are slight syntax errors:

onclick="close_me(this)"; -> onclick="close_me(this);"

$(me).parent('new_field').remove(); -> $(me).parent('.new_field').remove();